# How to get a user's browsing time on an Android device?

Tags: android

I want to count how long user browsing the web, using browser apps such as Firefox and Chrome. In JavaScript I have done this, but in Android I can't. When a user start browsing that time this program start count time. And feedback how long user spent time on browse.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. What do you mean "browsing Android Studio"? Usually browsing means using a web browser to explore the internet. Android Studio is a programming editor to help build Android apps.

Comment: I want to write if statement to check another app(Like crome,firefox)is running or not. Like is crome is open than......                                                   if(crome running){cont=5;}  how can i check crome is running or not into android. Please ans me. It is very needed to khow.

Comment: OK, I have removed Android Studio from your question, since the question is not about your Java editor.

Comment: How can i make u understand that it is about android.And i want to make alert in my app when another app running.OK?

Comment: I don't understand. You mentioned Android in your question, so presumably you want this thing to run on the Android operating system for mobile devices.